# A ping between to raspbian fails

Tags: raspbian, networking

I have several PI's with rasbian installed on it. When i try to ping an raspbian pi from another raspbian pi, i only get

> ping radio.local
>
> ping: unknown host radio.local

When i do the same on my ubuntu, it works. When i ping raspbmc.local (another pi) from an raspbian pi, it also works:

> PING raspbmc.local (192.168.0.17) 56(84) bytes of data.
>
> 64 bytes from raspbmc.local (192.168.0.17): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=9.52 ms

I have installed the package avahi-daemon on the radio pi.

Because i can ping the raspbmc.local, but not the radio.local, i guess there is a configuration issue on the radio.local.

Comment: Did you check if the hostname really is 'radio'. A ps should show something similar to this: 
6722 ?        S      0:00 avahi-daemon: running [radio.local]

Comment: Are you able to ping from radio.local Pi to the other?<br>
Is there any chance of a firewall on the radio.local blocking the ping/responsible for it not replying to pings?

Answer (score 2):

`radio.local` is a ZeroConf address, it's known only when zeroconf (or avahi) is installed. your ubintu has it, but Raspberry Pi has not.

instead of `radio.local` you should use the IP address to specify in your ping commands. for example in `PING raspbmc.local (192.168.0.17) 56(84) bytes of data.` the IP address is 192.168.0.17 -- use it with `ping` command to access your Pis.

instead of

```
ping raspbmc.local
```

type

```
ping 192.168.0.XX
```

where XX is the number you can find using ping command on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You must have installed some kind of mDNS software. Otherwise your hostname will not be registered unter the .local domain. That's not raspbian specific issue. Check if your mDNS service is really running. If not try the following:

Install mDNS service on you Raspberry Pi:

```
sudo apt-get install libnss-mdns
```

That's the magic and should result to what you expected. 
After the installation type

> ps ax

You should have the avahi-daemon running similar to this:

```
 6722 ?        S      0:00 avahi-daemon: running [radio.local]
 6723 ?        S      0:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
```

You should also check your hostname. Maybe that it's not 'radio'.

Comment: Unfortunately libnss-mdns is already installed (on both). the avahi-daemon also runs on both.

Comment: ok, did you check gereral connectivity? Is you Pi reachable via direct IP Adress? ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. And vice versa are you able to ping any host in your network from your radio Pi?